# rewrite componentDidUpdate(prevProps) into a hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to rewrite this life cycle metod into a hook:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.lng !== prevProps.lng && this.props.lat !== prevProps.lat) {
    this.map.setView(new L.LatLng(this.props.lat, this.props.lng), 6);
  } else if (this.props.mapTheme !== prevProps.mapTheme) {
    this.setMapTheme(this.props.mapTheme);
  }
}
```

I know to use a useEffect hook but couldn't find a good example.

Comment: is it correct that *both* `lng` and `lat` should be changed to trigger `.setView()` in initial code?

Comment: @skyboyer yes....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
  map.setView(new L.LatLng(props.lat, props.lng), 6);
}, [props.lng, props.lat]);

useEffect(() => {
  setMapTheme(props.mapTheme);
}, [props.mapTheme]);
```

Comment: according to OP `useEffect` should be run only when both `lng` and `lat` change. By listing them as dependencies in `useEffect` we will get `map.setView` called on any dependency is changed. I'm almost sure it would not cause any issue but just in case want to highlight this difference.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to use the `this` keyword since this wouldn't be a class component anymore.